# How to add Search_fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I tried to add search fields in Django using python. Followings are the codes that I have used.

```
# admin.py file

from django.db import models
from blog.models import Blog
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(Blog)

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date Created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Date Updated")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date Created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Date Updated")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body

class CommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment


class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ['title','body']
    list_filter = ('Date Created','Date Updated')
    inlines = [CommentInline]

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('post','author','body_first_60','created','updated')
    list_filter = ('Date Created','Date Updated')
```

I tried to add a search_fields for title and body by using Following code.

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    . . .
    search_fields = ('title','body')
    . . .
```

When I run this I can't see any search box. Why is that ? I want your help. I'm just a beginner.
Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The search fields should be a list, not a tuple.

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    . . .
    search_fields = ['title','body']
    . . .
```

Then make sure that you associate this admin object with the model.

```
admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

**EDIT:**

It's hard to tell from above, but you should consider just importing the models from models.py instead of redefining them in your admin.py file. Again, it looks like that's what you're doing above.

admin.py:

```
from django.db import models
from blog.models import Blog
from django.contrib import admin

class CommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','created','updated',)
    search_fields = ['title','body',]
    list_filter = ('Date Created','Date Updated',)
    inlines = [CommentInline,]

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('post','author','body_first_60','created','updated',)
    list_filter = ('Date Created','Date Updated',)

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date Created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Date Updated")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date Created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Date Updated")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

Comment: I have already added this "admin.site.register(Blog)" but when I'm trying to add this "admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)" browser shows an error called "NameError at /admin/"...and still have the same problem.

Comment: @Grant, make sure that you import Blog from <your app>.models - "from myapp.models import Blog". This should be at the top with the other import statements.

Comment: my importing like follows:::::::::: Is this correct ??
from blog.models import Blog
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
admin.site.register(Blog)

Comment: @Grant post your admin.py in the question above or in a pastebin (pastebin.com/)

Comment: I have posted my admin file :)

Comment: "The search fields should be a list, not a tuple." What makes you think so? `(admin.E126) The value of 'search_fields' must be a list or tuple.`

Answer (score 0):

You should register your site at the bottom of the site rather than at the top.
Please try admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin) at the bottom of the page. 
I hope that will solve your question